# Finding normal vector passing through a point

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have a line defined as $r(t) = a + tb$, where $a$ and $b$ are vectors. 
$p$ is a point on the line when $t = t_1$.
How do i obtain a normal vector to the line that passes through $p$?

According to [How to find normal vector of line given point normal passes through](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270151/how-to-find-normal-vector-of-line-given-point-normal-passes-through), 
the normal is simply $a + t_1 * b - p$?

But why is that the answer? point $a$ is not even on our normal line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While $a$ is not (necessarily) a point on the normal line, $r=a+t_1 b$ is. This is because $t_1$ was calculated exactly such that a the normal line would intersect the line you started with at this point. Thus, $r=a+t_1 b - p$ is exactly the vector connecting $p$ and the line orthogonally.

However, in the very special case that $p$ is already on the line, the question is ill-posed, as there is no well-defined direction in which the normal line would point, starting at $p$. In that case, an infinite amount of normal lines would be possible, forming the plane orthogonally intersecting your line at $p$.